# Set "Notes" in Device Info via MQTT on Cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

While registring a new Machine with static templates via MQTT I couldn't find a way to put something into the "Notes" Field at Device Profile in the Device Info.

Is there a template or another way to put some additional Information in that Textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no static template for setting the notes but you can create your own inventory PUT template. The fragment for this text box is simply c8y_Notes which is a string.

[image: Custom template to set notes]

To use the template you would send:

```
123,<serialOfDevice>,"My device notes"
```

I recommend to use quotes for longer strings to handle line breaks etc. correctly.